# Im a renter that recently noticed walls really bending zhould i be worried

Tags: walls, old-house, damage

Ive been renting an older house for about 3yrs now and the past 7 months or so I  started noticing the walls didnt look even anymore they looked like they were curving. Then in spring I came downstairs to a bunch of flying termites, I told my landlord but he said not to worry  and if I saw more this spring to let him know but I feel like they're getting worse and worse, even the baseboard doesn't look the same, it's like its disattatching, I'm a single mom with 2 kids on low income should I be worried or am I over reacting?

Comment: A few pictures so we can see what you see would be helpful.

Comment: yes pictures and yes if your walls are curving I would for sure be worried.

Comment: inform the landlord in writing and have him sign a copy so that he/she does not come back and say "you never told me"

Comment: If the walls are bowing top to bottom, that’s a real problem and needs attention immediately. (It doesn’t mater if the walls bow inward or outward, that’s a serious problem.) if the walls “snake” along the floor (weave in and out) that could be bad construction. In any event, if either condition just occurred, it needs immediate attention.